# Performance when accessing file system metadata concurrently

Tags: performance, file, concurrency, hard-drive

I have to collect certain attributes of files (modification date and so on). But there are many small files to analyze.

My question is: would it be more performant if I read, say, 3 or 4 files at the same time? If you access a file on the web this is better since you have to wait for the server to respond. But what about a harddisk? Is the concurrent strategy faster if the files are already cached by the harddisk?

Comment: Are you just reading metadata from the filesystem (stat or the equivalent) or reading data from the files themselves?

Comment: Just metadata (file size, creation date...)

Comment: You can definitely parallelize it then.  A lot of your "computation" will be unpacking the structure into your language/storage construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing metadata, it seems (mtime), which are stored in the file's inode and therefore in the file system. Your limiting factor should (in UNIX terms) be the syscall to get the `stat` information, which could profit from parallelization.